# Customer Managed Key in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating a Azure Data Factory with customer managed key using Terraform as below:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                = "example"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  customer_managed_key_id = var.cmkID 
  customer_managed_key_identity_id = var.IdentityID
  
}
```

I have already created a PrimaryEncryptionKey and added to Key vault Keys. And passed those values in tfvars file.
Terraform plan looks fine, When Terraform plan is applied it throws error

**Operation failed. Data factory Managed Identity does not have access to customer managed Key vault**

Since the data factory is not created yet, I dont have a identity of data factory to be added to Key vault access policy. So I removed the customer managed key variables from terraform code and created a simple data factory.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                = "example"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
```

This went fine and I was able to add the object ID of data factory along with Identity App id in key vault access policies.
After this I again ran the first code with customer managed key information. This time I got a new error as below:

**Updatefactory failed.You cannot add CMK settings for factories with existing entities.**

I have tried removing the integration run time that is created by default( which got created along with sample data factory) but in vain.

This looks like a deadlock situation and I am not sure if I am missing any important information here.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create Azure data factory with CMK assigned:
But received error:

```
│ Error: creating/updating Data Factory: (Factory Name "kaaexample" / Resource Group "xxx"): datafactory.FactoriesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to 
request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="CMKAccessDeniedByCallerNotAuthorized" Message="Operation failed. Data Factory Managed Identity doesn't have access to customer managed key vault."
│
```

[image]

*`Make sure  to Enable Soft Delete and Do Not Purge on Azure Key Vault`*

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "this" {
  name = "example-user-id"
resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
location = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                = "kaaexample"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.this.id]
  } 
}


resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "cmkkaakeyvault"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
 tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
// tenant_id           = data.azuread_client_config.current.tenant_id
 
   purge_protection_enabled    = true
   soft_delete_retention_days = 7

  sku_name = "standard"
}


Note:
Dedicated  access policy is needed for the client if no  role assignmentis present .GetRotationPolicy is mandatory whether you actively use it or not. 

The client should have RBAC roles like Key Vault Crypto Officer or Key Vault Administrator or an assigned Key Vault Access Policy with permissions Create,Delete,Get,Purge,Recover,Update and GetRotationPolicy for keys without Rotation Policy.
```

[image]

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "example" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id

  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
//    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id  

  key_permissions = [
 "Backup", "Decrypt", 
  "Encrypt",  "Import", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Sign", "UnwrapKey", "Update", 
  "Verify", "WrapKey", "Release", "Rotate", "GetRotationPolicy", "SetRotationPolicy",
    "Create", "Delete", "Get"

  ]
}
```

> **Note:** **Create ADF without any entities i.e;  Data flow or linked services initially and assigned the user assigned identity.**

After the above code is executed and ADF is created without CMK .

**Then create ADF with Custom managed key:**

- Make sure the ADf managed identity has proper role to access keyvault keys or access policies like "unwrapKey",   "wrapKey", "Rotate", "GetRotationPolicy", "SetRotationPolicy",   "Create", "Delete", "Get"

**Code:**

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "example" {
  name         = "cmkexamplekey"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 4096
  

  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "sign",
    "unwrapKey",
    "verify",
    "wrapKey",
  ]

   depends_on = [ 
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.example
   ]
  
}


output "key" {
  value = azurerm_key_vault_key.example.version
  
}


resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                = "kaaexample"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    customer_managed_key_id  = azurerm_key_vault_key.example.id
    customer_managed_key_identity_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.this.id
    

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.this.id]
  
}
}
```

[image]

ADF :

[image]

**Reference :** [Add Customer-managed Key to Git-managed Data Factory via Terraform | by Gerrit Stapper](https://medium.com/twodigits/azure-terraform-add-customer-managed-key-to-git-managed-data-factory-via-terraform-4f7c56250b98)

Comment: Hi @kavya, It created the datafactory but the pipeline we imported are failing. We could see that the existing datafactory with no customer managed key is working fine. but the new one is failing